# Set a new, specific value for SQL sequence

Tags: sql-server-2012, tsql-sequence

I have created a sequence to my database as follows:

```
DECLARE @max int;
SELECT @max = MAX(customernumber)+1
FROM organisation

exec('CREATE SEQUENCE organisation_customernumber_sequence
    START WITH ' + @max +
'   INCREMENT BY 1;')
```

It works and can be used in the application as intended.
However, now there's a requirement to have it start from the number 40000.

Somehow I've managed to not find a way to do this. What is the simplest way to set my organisation_customernumber_sequence to 40000 with a single query?

Comment: I haven't used sequences much, but isn't it just a case of using `STARTS WITH 40000`?

Comment: Well, I actually found it. It would be ALTER SEQUENCE organisation_customernumber_sequence RESTART WITH 40000; You can answer that and I'll check it as correct answer.

Comment: I hate to take credit where credit is not due - why don't you answer it instead :)

Answer (score 0):

ALTER SEQUENCE organisation_customernumber_sequence RESTART WITH 40000;

GO